# PyQt QtWebengineWidgets with PyQt 5.12

Tags: pyqt5, cx-freeze, qtwebengine

I got some issues with QtWebengine and PyQt5.12.

my story from beginning on:

- Make a program and use PyQt for a GUI
- use cx_freeze to make it easier available for my colleagues
- realize a problem with my current version of PyQt5.12 respectively QtWebenginewidgets (for shortness'sake WEW)
- find out, that PyQt5.12 does not include the WEW anymore -> ok no problem, just install them via `pip`
- realize that it still does not work.
- reverse engineering via PyQt 5.11.3 (WEW still included) --> no issue with compiled program.

My actual question is now, why does it not work with PyQt/PyQt QtWebengineWidgets 5.12?

I got 64bit Python (`platform.architecture()[0]` returns so), and `pip list` returns current versions:

- cx-Freeze                          6.0b1
- PyQt5                              5.12.1
- PyQtWebEngine                      5.12.1

My code also includes

`from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView`

It is not tragic as the fallback variant with PyQt 5.11.3 works, but for the future i just want to know the real rootcause for that behavior.
i kindly ask for your input.

PS: Windows10 with anaconda 5.0.2 with pip-maintained mostly up2date modules.

EDIT:
I just realized i forgot one thing, I had to do with PyQt5.11.3 as well: Copy the whole PyQt5 folder from the Site-packages directory of anaconda to the lib-folder of the cx_freeze build folder. looks like, there is something not imported. maybe I will have time to investigate this and share my knowledge here.

Answer (score 1):

since version 5.12, QtWebEngineWidgets has been moved to an other package called PyQtWebEngine. it has to be separatly installed. You can have a look at https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtwebengine/intro

Comment: Your answer does not contribute anything, the OP indicates that you are using PyQtWebEngine.